# No Time Sheets available for employee to fill out

Tags: hours

We come to work all the time and the time sheets that we have to hand fill out are not available, HR hasn't sent them out. Is there a law that says these time sheets must be made available on the day you work? We are regularly called in on our day off and there is no time sheet to write down your hours. Or the time sheets are taken up early because of a weekend or holiday, so you can't write down your time? You have to wait until the next week when HR is back to track them down and add your time. Our fear is that sometime we are going to forget a day and not get paid for it.

Comment: Are you able to record your time on your own, before you officially report it to HR? Has HR ever disputed times people have claimed?

Comment: No photocopier? Excel?

Comment: Track it on your own

Comment: Answering "Is there a law?" requires knowing your jurisdiction: please add that. Are you paid by the hour according to your timesheet? What is your employment status? How do HR justify collecting timesheets early so you can't include some of your time, and how is that practically different from not being able to record time because they haven't given you a timesheet?

Answer (score 6):

Seriously, take an empty sheet of paper, write “Timesheet” and your name at the top, and fill in your hours.

If that isn’t accepted by HR then ask here again.

And if they are not paying for time that you worked when they are messing around with time sheets, call them and demand that it is sorted out immediately. Not paying you for your work is unacceptable and illegal in most places.

Comment: _Not paying you for your work is unacceptable_ Please inform Mr D Trump

Comment: @Ed I assume he knows. And I’d recommend to anyone being not paid to think very hard if they shouldn’t get a job elsewhere.

Comment: Legislative branch passes funding bills not the Executive branch.